# join tables on like with index

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table of URLs (domains and pages)

```
URLs
-----
url_id

url
```

I have a list of domain names, that I want to see if are contained in the URLs table.

so if I have a domain in my list: 
http://stackoverflow.com

I want it to match the URLs.url record of:

https://stackoverflow.com/question/230479

https://stackoverflow.com/question/395872364

etc

The URL table is quite large, 10million+ and will grow

The list of domain names I want to test will vary between 1-10k

Currently I am creating a temp table of the list of domains, then joining to the URLs table to find all URLs that match

```
SELECT * from URLs
JOIN tmp_table_domains on tmp_table_domain.domain like URLs.url || '%'
```

I have indexed the URLs.url and the tmp_table_domain.domain, with the thinking that indexing will work as the wild card is on the right.

However, EXPLAIN ANALYSE doesn't show any index being used. An old post mentioned that postgres 8.x cannot like join with index, but I could find nothing else to back this up or alternatives or whether it applies to newer versions

If it helps, my postgres is 9.1. If upgrading will fix this, that is fine, only reason haven't upgraded is not been any reason to that I am aware of

Edit_1
 this is a first database project have worked on and am learning it all as I go along

I don't mind ripping out all of the above and using whatever works better, whether that is a temp table / array / better query

edit_2

```
 GroupAggregate  (cost=1429152.90..1435118.48 rows=340890 width=44) (actual time=157905.450..157905.609 rows=27 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=1429152.90..1430005.13 rows=340890 width=44) (actual time=157905.425..157905.451 rows=29 loops=1)
         Sort Key: task_items.task_item
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 29kB
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=14210.95..1387337.41 rows=340890 width=44) (actual time=18216.187..157905.055 rows=29 loops=1)
               Join Filter: ((task_items.task_item)::text ~~ ((tmp_domains.domain)::text || '%'::text))
               ->  Hash Join  (cost=14210.95..194126.53 rows=14066 width=44) (actual time=452.262..7953.639 rows=13737 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: (task_items.task_id = tasks.task_id)
                     ->  Seq Scan on task_items  (cost=0.00..170062.71 rows=2589924 width=48) (actual time=0.019..4480.360 rows=2575206 loops=1)
                           Filter: (task_item_status_id = 2)
                     ->  Hash  (cost=14205.68..14205.68 rows=421 width=4) (actual time=440.409..440.409 rows=171 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 7kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on tasks  (cost=0.00..14205.68 rows=421 width=4) (actual time=101.491..439.821 rows=171 loops=1)
                                 Filter: ((account_detail_id = 695) AND (base_action_type_id <> ALL ('{1,3,4}'::integer[])))
               ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..109.70 rows=4847 width=32) (actual time=0.002..4.924 rows=4536 loops=13737)
                     ->  Seq Scan on tmp_domains  (cost=0.00..85.47 rows=4847 width=32) (actual time=0.010..5.851 rows=4536 loops=1)
 Total runtime: 157907.403 ms
```

The actual query is a bit different to the simplified explanation above.

task_items has just under 7million rows
and the tmp_domains has 4,500

### tl;dr

so to summarise. What is the best way to partial match a list of strings to a column

Comment: but why a temporary table? And please do post your explain output

Comment: because I don't really know what I am doing and hacking at various things and this is currently the best I have :-) Before it was just a big WHERE url LIKE 'http://domain1.com%' OR 'http://domain2.com%' OR ...'http://domain9999.com%'

Comment: where does the content for your tmp domains table come from?

Comment: It comes from an external process via a message queue. Basically I have a python function that receives a list and I want to find all existing items that match it

Comment: added the explain analyse output. The actual query is a bit different to the simplified version originally stated, the only main difference is task_items is the URLs table

Comment: Your `where` condition: `task_item_status_id = 2` reduces the number of rows from `taks_items` down to 2.5 millions. Do you have an index on that column? Maybe try a combined index on `task_items (task_item_status_id, task_item)` - this might be more efficient in a current version of Postgres though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name no there is no index there (now adding). This will be the 4th index on this table, which I think, may be too many as it gets lots of inserts and deletes, about 50k per day inserts, 40k per day deletes

Comment: With the index on task_item_status it ran a bit slower! 161419.760 ms vs 157907.403 ms before

Comment: Went with something like this in the end, just added a "domain" column to the table, ugly and hacky but is working. Will leave question open for a bit as in my investigations, I think something would be possible with postgres string functions, but it was getting quite complicated. If no better solutions come will make this as answer

Answer (score 0):

A few months back Peter Eisentraut published the [`pguri` extension](https://github.com/petere/pguri/releases/tag/1.20150415) which can greatly simplify your work. It is currently only source code so you'd have to build the library code, which is very easy on any Linux box, then place the files in the PG installation directory and finally `CREATE EXTENSION` in your database. After that you can do simple queries like:

```
SELECT *
FROM urls
JOIN tmp_table_domains d ON uri_host(d.domain::uri) = uri_host(urls.url::uri);
```

Note that this will also match between different schemes, so an `http://` domain will match the corresponding `https://` url. If you do not want that, then also join on `uri_scheme()` for both domain and url.

Indexes will work on the `text` data type that the functions of the extension returns. If your database uses `UTF-8` encoding you should create your index somewhat like this:

```
CREATE INDEX url_index ON urls (uri_host(url::uri) text_pattern_ops);
```

And then also for your domain names table.

You can `ALTER TABLE urls ALTER COLUMN url SET DATA TYPE uri` so you can forego the casts.

Comment: Definitely looks like something to keep an eye, but in the end the build from source and the fact I may need to match partial non urls eg 1234_abcd needs to match 1234 meant didn't check further with this